# Is it possible to access an Azure Media Services DASH streaming URL from a secure website?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I have published a video to Azure Media Services and I am trying to open that video on an SSL-enabled website using the new Azure Media Player.

I have added a video tag to my page as per the [documentation](http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html), i.e:

```
<video id="vid1" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin" controls width="640" height="400" poster="poster.jpg" data-setup='{"logo": { "enabled": false}, "nativeControlsForTouch": false}'>
    <source src="http://example.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/.../example.ism/manifest" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />
    <p class="amp-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
    </p>
</video>
```

However when I load the page Chrome and Firefox throw a Mixed Content error:
[image]

I believe this is due to the DASH url that is generated and processed by Azure Media Player. I can get the video to load and play if I change the video tag to the following:

```
<video id="vid1" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin" controls width="640" height="400" poster="poster.jpg" data-setup='{"logo": { "enabled": false}, "nativeControlsForTouch": false}'>
    <source src="http://example.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/.../example.ism/manifest" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" data-setup='{"streamingFormats": ["SMOOTH", "HLS-V3", "HLS-V4"] }' />
    <p class="amp-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
    </p>
</video>
```

However this seems to force Azure Media Player into using Flash and the user experience is not all that great (slow to load, jumpy playback, etc).

Is it possible to stream a video that is hosted in Azure Media Services via a DASH streaming url to a secure website using Azure Media Player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that streaming endpoints that were created before September 11, 2014 **do not** support streaming over ssl, however streaming endpoints that were created on or after September 11, 2014 do support streaming over ssl.

The streaming endpoint I was using was created at the start of 2014 and therefore did not support ssl. The solution was to create a new streaming endpoint and use its publish url instead.

Be aware that if you need to create a new streaming endpoint like I did you will probably want to turn off your old endpoint and remove the streaming units associated with it so you don't incur unnecessary costs.